# ffmpeg : Conversion to mkv with compatibility with Samsung BluRay

Tags: ffmpeg, compatibility, h.264, mkv

I have several videos (FullHD resolution) which I want to convert to mkv format and play on my Samsung BluRay Player (model BD-J5900).
Based on User Manual (http://media.datatail.com/docs/manual/252846_en.pdf , page 6) it supports mkv playing if codecs are:

- Video : H.264 BP/MP/HP
- Audio : MP3

Thus, based on https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html the command to convert it into proper format is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -f matroska -vcodec libx264 -acodec mp3 output.mkv
```

It converts, but file is not playable on player. It say "Video format is not supported".

After checking info here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264 - I thought it may require some compatibility and change the command to :

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -f matroska -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -acodec mp3 output.mkv
```

But it also didn't help - player demonstrates the same error.

How to fix that?
Thanks!

Updated: 
Also tested following options

```
 ffmpeg -i input.file -f matroska -vcodec libx264 -preset veryslow -x264-params bluray_compat=1 -acodec mp3 output.mkv
 ffmpeg -i input.file -f matroska -vcodec libx264 -preset veryslow -profile:v high -level 4.2 -x264-params bluray_compat=1 -acodec mp3 output.mkv
 ffmpeg -i input.file -f matroska -vcodec libx264 -preset veryslow -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -x264-params bluray_compat=1 -acodec mp3 output.mkv
 ffmpeg -i input.file -vcodec libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -preset veryslow -acodec mp3 output.mkv
```

Also not supported.

Updated:
Console output for command without profile flag:

```
ffmpeg version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000019abc2aa4c0] sample aspect ratio already set to 1:1, ignoring 'pasp' atom (65536:65536)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\Yehor\Desktop\video_conversion\input\VID_20180620_165336103.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-06-20T22:55:12.000000Z
    com.android.version: 7.0
  Duration: 00:01:34.19, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17178 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m), 1920x1080, 17016 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2018-06-20T22:55:12.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-06-20T22:55:12.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] using SAR=1/1time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] 264 - core 155 r2901 7d0ff22 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, matroska, to 'C:\Users\Yehor\Desktop\video_conversion\output\VID_20180620_165336103.mkv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    com.android.version: 7.0
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuvj420p(pc), 1080x1920 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 libx264
      creation_time   : 2018-06-20T22:55:12.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
      displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-06-20T22:55:12.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 libmp3lame
frame= 2823 fps= 15 q=-1.0 Lsize=   80210kB time=00:01:34.10 bitrate=6982.7kbits/s speed=0.492x
video:78692kB audio:1469kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.061441%
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] frame I:14    Avg QP:21.43  size:187644
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] frame P:728   Avg QP:23.93  size: 68336
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] frame B:2081  Avg QP:27.79  size: 13553
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] consecutive B-frames:  1.3%  0.6%  2.0% 96.1%
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] mb I  I16..4:  5.7% 71.5% 22.7%
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] mb P  I16..4:  2.0%  8.8%  0.9%  P16..4: 46.2% 20.0% 12.2%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:10.1%
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.9%  0.1%  B16..8: 45.3%  4.9%  1.0%  direct: 2.8%  skip:44.9%  L0:45.7% L1:47.3% BI: 7.0%
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] 8x8 transform intra:75.1% inter:69.7%
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 56.8% 70.0% 15.9% inter: 18.3% 19.2% 2.4%
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 18% 33% 15% 34%
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 17% 20% 24%  5%  8%  8%  8%  5%  5%
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 19% 13%  6%  9%  9%  9%  7%  5%
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 53% 23% 17%  7%
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:15.7% UV:2.6%
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] ref P L0: 49.7% 11.2% 25.9% 11.3%  1.9%
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] ref B L0: 88.2%  9.2%  2.6%
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] ref B L1: 96.2%  3.8%
[libx264 @ 0000019abc348e00] kb/s:6843.33
```

Console output for command with profile flag:

```
ffmpeg version 4.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000018124b5b080] sample aspect ratio already set to 1:1, ignoring 'pasp' atom (65536:65536)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\Yehor\Desktop\video_conversion\input\VID_20180620_165336103.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-06-20T22:55:12.000000Z
    com.android.version: 7.0
  Duration: 00:01:34.19, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17178 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, smpte170m), 1920x1080, 17016 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2018-06-20T22:55:12.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-06-20T22:55:12.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0000018124bf9100] using SAR=1/1time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
[libx264 @ 0000018124bf9100] frame MB size (68x120) > level limit (1620)
[libx264 @ 0000018124bf9100] DPB size (1 frames, 8160 mbs) > level limit (0 frames, 8100 mbs)
[libx264 @ 0000018124bf9100] MB rate (244800) > level limit (40500)
[libx264 @ 0000018124bf9100] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0000018124bf9100] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0000018124bf9100] 264 - core 155 r2901 7d0ff22 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x131 me=umh subme=10 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=24 chroma_me=1 trellis=2 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=60 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, matroska, to 'C:\Users\Yehor\Desktop\video_conversion\output\VID_20180620_165336103.mkv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    com.android.version: 7.0
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuvj420p(pc), 1080x1920 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], q=-1--1, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 libx264
      creation_time   : 2018-06-20T22:55:12.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
      displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-06-20T22:55:12.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 libmp3lame
frame= 2823 fps= 11 q=-1.0 Lsize=  106243kB time=00:01:34.16 bitrate=9242.5kbits/s speed=0.358x
video:104723kB audio:1469kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.047877%
[libx264 @ 0000018124bf9100] frame I:14    Avg QP:24.31  size:181656
[libx264 @ 0000018124bf9100] frame P:2809  Avg QP:27.29  size: 37271
[libx264 @ 0000018124bf9100] mb I  I16..4: 24.0%  0.0% 76.0%
[libx264 @ 0000018124bf9100] mb P  I16..4:  2.7%  0.0%  2.0%  P16..4: 45.5% 15.6%  4.7%  0.4%  0.1%    skip:28.9%
[libx264 @ 0000018124bf9100] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 40.3% 61.3% 13.8% inter: 21.0% 20.2% 3.7%
[libx264 @ 0000018124bf9100] i16 v,h,dc,p: 22% 30% 23% 26%
[libx264 @ 0000018124bf9100] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 13% 15% 12%  9% 12% 12% 12%  9%  7%
[libx264 @ 0000018124bf9100] i8c dc,h,v,p: 52% 22% 18%  8%
[libx264 @ 0000018124bf9100] kb/s:9107.11
```

Comment: Added to first post (length of output is higher than comment size limit).

Comment: Possibly doesn't like the yuvj420p, but some devices are picky and it becomes a guessing game. Try `ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -c:a copy -t 10 out.mkv`.

Comment: OK, I will do it as soon as I get home to player. Meanwhile, I was thinking I shoud use -x264-params bluray_compat=1 in command : 
`ffmpeg -i input_video -f matroska -vcodec libx264 -preset veryslow -x264-params bluray_compat=1 -acodec mp3 output.mkv`

Comment: Nope. Neither `-vf format=yuv420p` or adding `-x264-params bluray_compat=1` didn't work. Also tried with various profiles: "baseline", "high" and without profile specifying. Any other guesses?

Comment: The device also supports MP4. Video decoder section claims it supports H.264 Constrained Baseline, Main, and High profiles, up to level 4.1. Lazy test is to try MP4: `ffmpeg -i input -c copy -t 10 output.mp4`.

Comment: Maybe dumb question,  but why do you specify the `-c copy` in command instead of pushing it to `-c:v libx264`? There will be several files and not all of them would have h264 in original encoding.

Comment: I was assuming you were dealing with the single input, or multiple inputs all with H.264 & AAC.

Comment: OK. That's weird. I had several files with native h264-video and acc-audio (mp4) and my player can reed them. If I'm converting any of those with commands:
`ffmpeg -i input.file -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mkv` or `ffmpeg -i input.file -vcodec copy -acodec mp3 output.mkv` player is able to read them. If using `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec mp3 output.mkv` or `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec h264 -acodec mp3 output.mkv` output is unreadable.
What could be the reason?

Comment: Hard to say with devices. You'll just have to keep trying with your process of elimination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved with this code:

```
ffmpeg -f matroska -i input_file.*** -c:v libx264  -preset veryslow -crf 23 -profile:v high -level:v 4.1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags global_header -c:a aac output_file.mkv
```

Tested with ffmpeg 4.0.2 on Windows 10 [x64]
Probably, there is a room to play with CRF to decrease the size of final file.

Comment: `-f matroska` should be omitted